# Why I am having error Call to undefined function get_header() using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using twenty eleven for my theme and I create a PHP page under it named results.php in the results.php here's my code:

```
    <?php

get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

From my index.php:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<a href="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/result.php">Main</a>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: are you making a custom page with `result.php` file??

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more detail of what the point of the question is. Because, the way I see it, if you're using the right twenty eleven template, it will work if you go to http://yourdomain.com/result.php

Comment: I am creating a custom page in the theme I can already access the page but the function inside the page it prompts error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a custom page on the wordpress,

Then you have to set the template name into your file like in your `result.php`:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: Result */
    get_header();

    // Rest Stuff for result.php

    get_footer();
?>
```

hope this will solve your problem..

**UPDATE:** Please don't use the direct link that you are given in your index.php file something like

`<a href="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/result.php">Main</a>`

Because you are calling directly to the `result.php` but the best way is to create a page with the name `Main` from the backend and select the `Result` theme for that particular page.

Comment: so what will i put in my href ?

Comment: with a small trick just create a page with the name `Main` and copy the `Permalink: http://localhost/jwp/?page_id=4` below the page name, this is because if you want to put the `href=""` link on your page.

Comment: I do not understand the answer.   The first part of your answer appears to be the same as the question, with extra space and two comments. The second part is an href; i do not think this has anything to do with the php error.  Help me to understand what i am missing here.

Comment: @DarinCardin, The error is because the OP the link like this ```<a href="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/result.php">Main</a>``` and this is not the way to access the URL in WordPress.